# How to get bounders of some portion of text in FabricJS?

Tags: fabricjs

I'm curious if there is a way to find X, Y, WIDTH, and HEIGHT of some portion of a text by using a native function or even workaround?

The purpose of that is that I'll need to draw some rectangle on top of it when client types that word in another Input, kind of word existence indicator... similar to search...

Here is the Textbox example where I need to find "boundaries" of the word **NOT** (red text)

[image: Example Text]

[image]